# SoftLayer Object Storage Access Log

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How can we get the access log of Object storage on `SoftLayer`?

I would like to use swift based one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this information is not available, I recommend to submit a ticket if it's really necessary to get this kind of information

Comment: Thank you, Ruber. I got it. Can we use "Access Trail" service on Bluemix for this kind of matter?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure about "Access Trail" service on Bluemix (I'm from SoftLayer's side), is this a service for Object Storage?

Comment: I"Access Trail" seems to be able to trail Bluemix service API access log however SoftLayer API is out of scope.

Comment: I believe that service works for Bluemix API, but Object Storage has its own API and the only way to get this kind of information "Access Logs" is through SoftLayer